# Tokenize sentence in word in UTF-8 with special characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, utf-8, tokenize

I am trying to tokenize the words in a sentence in Javascript (node.js), removing non-word chars (point, comma, period, question mark, etc.), taking into account every existing alphabet in UTF-8 (english, latin, greek, cyrillic, japanese, etc.) and numbers, that means I need a way to know if a character is a part of a word, or is a symbol. For example:

`españa.es 4*5 Rußland Citroën, 東京 iphone-pro5`

should return an array:

`[españa, es, 4, 5, Rußland, Citroën, 東京, iphone, pro5]`

I'm using the following regular expression:

`[0-9A-Za-zªº\u00B5\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02AF\u02B0-\u02C1\u0370-\u0374\u0376-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03FF\u0400-\u0481\u048A-\u0523]+`

> 0-9A-Za-z (numbers and English letters)
>
> ªº (ordinal indicators)
>
> \u00B5 (micro sign)
>
> \u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02AF (non-english latin letters)
>
> \u02B0-\u02C1 (modifier letters)
>
> \u0370-\u0374\u0376-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03FF (greek and Coptic alphabets)
>
> \u0400-\u0481\u048A-\u0523 (cyrillic alphabet)

Is there any other easier or more complete way to split words in a text?

Comment: Use XRegExp: https://jsfiddle.net/uhwt8e4k/

Comment: Why not just split by non-word chars (which are mostly the same in all languages) instead of matching word chars?

Comment: @hindmost, it is not so easy, for example `\u00D7 (×)`, `\u00F7 (÷)`, `\u1f600 ()`, `1f4a9 ()` are symbols, and cannot be part of words (there are a lot of those symbols in UTF-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy with `XRegExp`:

```js
var s = "españa.es 4*5 Rußland Citroën, 東京 iphone-pro5";
var r = XRegExp("[\\pL\\pN]+", "g");
var results = XRegExp.match(s, r);
console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.1.1/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

The `[\\pL\\pN]+` regex pattern matches one or more Unicode letters (`\pL`) or digits (`\pN`).

Comment: XRegExp would just be doing a similar elongated regexp (like what the OP is already using) behind the scenes, so it's not really worthwhile to pull in an entire library just for a shortened string IMHO.

Comment: @mscdex: Certainly, if you do not want to pull in the whole library, you can just use the `\pL` and `\pN` constructs from that lib.

Comment: The standard regexp used in `\pL` can be found in https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/v3.1.1/xregexp-all.js#L1750

Comment: And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41698724/3832970) I described (in a nutshell) how to use that.