# C# RegEx Letters Only With International Support

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to validate that the text box entry is 3-20 characters long and is letters only, but allowing for accented characters like; é

Using online RegEx testers, the expression I have written "seems" to be correct, but used on a web form, it doesn't seem to allow anything at all. Can anybody suggest what I am doing wrong? Many thanks

```
ValidationExpression="^[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}]{3,20}$"
```

Comment: Please review my answer below and provide feedback. I think you need some more clarification, but you need to be more specific.

Comment: Is the regex on your web form evaluated in the front-end in JavaScript in c# on code behind?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to match lower or uppercase letters with separate Unicode category classes.
You may use `\p{L}` straight:

```
var ValidationExpression = @"^\p{L}{3,20}$";
var result = Regex.IsMatch(s, ValidationExpression);
```

Note that to avoid matching 3 to 20 letters before a trailing LF symbol, you may replace `$` with `\z` anchor:

```
var ValidationExpression = @"^\p{L}{3,20}\z";
```

See the [.NET regex demo online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cp%7bL%7d%7b3%2c20%7d%5cz&i=%c5%81ab%c4%87%d0%af%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%88%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%a1%d0%a3%d0%bc%d0%b0).

To make it work on the ***client side*** in an ASP.NET app, you will have to either make sure you only support ECMAScript 2018 compliant browsers (like Chrome) or use a regex with custom letter ranges/sets like

```
ValidationExpression="^(?:[A-Za-z\xAA\xB5\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u066E\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5\u06E6\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u07F4\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0-\u08B4\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0980\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0AF9\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58-\u0C5A\u0C60\u0C61\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0\u0CE1\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D5F-\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F5\u13F8-\u13FD\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16F1-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE\u1BAF\u1BBA-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C7D\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303B\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FD5\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA61F\uA62A\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA69D\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA7AD\uA7B0-\uA7B7\uA7F7-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA8FD\uA90A-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF\uA9E0-\uA9E4\uA9E6-\uA9EF\uA9FA-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA7E-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB65\uAB70-\uABE2\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]|\uD86E[\uDC00-\uDC1D\uDC20-\uDFFF]|\uD86D[\uDC00-\uDF34\uDF40-\uDFFF]|\uD869[\uDC00-\uDED6\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD803[\uDC00-\uDC48\uDC80-\uDCB2\uDCC0-\uDCF2]|\uD83A[\uDC00-\uDCC4]|\uD801[\uDC00-\uDC9D\uDD00-\uDD27\uDD30-\uDD63\uDE00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF67]|\uD800[\uDC00-\uDC0B\uDC0D-\uDC26\uDC28-\uDC3A\uDC3C\uDC3D\uDC3F-\uDC4D\uDC50-\uDC5D\uDC80-\uDCFA\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEA0-\uDED0\uDF00-\uDF1F\uDF30-\uDF40\uDF42-\uDF49\uDF50-\uDF75\uDF80-\uDF9D\uDFA0-\uDFC3\uDFC8-\uDFCF]|\uD80D[\uDC00-\uDC2E]|\uD87E[\uDC00-\uDE1D]|\uD81B[\uDF00-\uDF44\uDF50\uDF93-\uDF9F]|[\uD80C\uD840-\uD868\uD86A-\uD86C\uD86F-\uD872][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD805[\uDC80-\uDCAF\uDCC4\uDCC5\uDCC7\uDD80-\uDDAE\uDDD8-\uDDDB\uDE00-\uDE2F\uDE44\uDE80-\uDEAA\uDF00-\uDF19]|\uD81A[\uDC00-\uDE38\uDE40-\uDE5E\uDED0-\uDEED\uDF00-\uDF2F\uDF40-\uDF43\uDF63-\uDF77\uDF7D-\uDF8F]|\uD809[\uDC80-\uDD43]|\uD802[\uDC00-\uDC05\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC35\uDC37\uDC38\uDC3C\uDC3F-\uDC55\uDC60-\uDC76\uDC80-\uDC9E\uDCE0-\uDCF2\uDCF4\uDCF5\uDD00-\uDD15\uDD20-\uDD39\uDD80-\uDDB7\uDDBE\uDDBF\uDE00\uDE10-\uDE13\uDE15-\uDE17\uDE19-\uDE33\uDE60-\uDE7C\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEC0-\uDEC7\uDEC9-\uDEE4\uDF00-\uDF35\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF72\uDF80-\uDF91]|\uD835[\uDC00-\uDC54\uDC56-\uDC9C\uDC9E\uDC9F\uDCA2\uDCA5\uDCA6\uDCA9-\uDCAC\uDCAE-\uDCB9\uDCBB\uDCBD-\uDCC3\uDCC5-\uDD05\uDD07-\uDD0A\uDD0D-\uDD14\uDD16-\uDD1C\uDD1E-\uDD39\uDD3B-\uDD3E\uDD40-\uDD44\uDD46\uDD4A-\uDD50\uDD52-\uDEA5\uDEA8-\uDEC0\uDEC2-\uDEDA\uDEDC-\uDEFA\uDEFC-\uDF14\uDF16-\uDF34\uDF36-\uDF4E\uDF50-\uDF6E\uDF70-\uDF88\uDF8A-\uDFA8\uDFAA-\uDFC2\uDFC4-\uDFCB]|\uD804[\uDC03-\uDC37\uDC83-\uDCAF\uDCD0-\uDCE8\uDD03-\uDD26\uDD50-\uDD72\uDD76\uDD83-\uDDB2\uDDC1-\uDDC4\uDDDA\uDDDC\uDE00-\uDE11\uDE13-\uDE2B\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE88\uDE8A-\uDE8D\uDE8F-\uDE9D\uDE9F-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEDE\uDF05-\uDF0C\uDF0F\uDF10\uDF13-\uDF28\uDF2A-\uDF30\uDF32\uDF33\uDF35-\uDF39\uDF3D\uDF50\uDF5D-\uDF61]|\uD808[\uDC00-\uDF99]|\uD83B[\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05-\uDE1F\uDE21\uDE22\uDE24\uDE27\uDE29-\uDE32\uDE34-\uDE37\uDE39\uDE3B\uDE42\uDE47\uDE49\uDE4B\uDE4D-\uDE4F\uDE51\uDE52\uDE54\uDE57\uDE59\uDE5B\uDE5D\uDE5F\uDE61\uDE62\uDE64\uDE67-\uDE6A\uDE6C-\uDE72\uDE74-\uDE77\uDE79-\uDE7C\uDE7E\uDE80-\uDE89\uDE8B-\uDE9B\uDEA1-\uDEA3\uDEA5-\uDEA9\uDEAB-\uDEBB]|\uD806[\uDCA0-\uDCDF\uDCFF\uDEC0-\uDEF8]|\uD811[\uDC00-\uDE46]|\uD82F[\uDC00-\uDC6A\uDC70-\uDC7C\uDC80-\uDC88\uDC90-\uDC99]|\uD82C[\uDC00\uDC01]|\uD873[\uDC00-\uDEA1]){3,20}$";
```

Comment: Thank you for replying and for your help. I've tried your RegEx in the web form but it still fails everything. I'm using it with a <asp:RegularExpressionValidator /> is that the problem? Do I need to adjust it for use on the client?

Comment: @user470249 Aha, the pattern will only work on the server side *unless* the JS environment is compatible with the ECMAScript 2018 standard. Then, `^\p{L}{3,20}$` will work. Else, you need to use a work around based on Unicode code point ranges. The easiest is to disable client side validation.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I thought it must be something to do with the client side environment. Is there anything I can use to allow ALL characters client site and then do a stricter validation on the server side? I tried \w but still only allows the standard [a-zA-Z] characters. Thanks again!

Comment: @user470249 You may have a look at [this resource](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7BL%7D&abb=on&g=&i=). This is showing all the letters in the `\p{L}` class. You may check *Escape* and click *Show Set* to see the Unicode code ranges. Note that C# regex does not support `\UXXXXXXXX` notation, you would need to transpile those. Also, you may grab the `\p{L}` alternative [from this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698470/unicode-ranges-of-pl-plu-and-pll/41698724#41698724).

Comment: @user470249 See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bLyZdJ/1), but the pattern is really long. Again, I think the best way is to skip client side validation. If you insist, you may use `^\S{3,20}$` to match 3 to 20 non-whitespace chars.