# How can I allow only alphanumeric including Chinese, Japanese and all that cryptographic languages?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently trying to filter out any bad char from a string to only allow alphanumeric ones but I need to include Chinese, Japanese and all that non-Latin languages as well. After some hours of reading RegEx, I'm more confused than informed. Currently I have:

```
let string = 'Test=查看         ' +
    '';

string = string.replace(/[^A-Za-z\d\p{Han}]+$/ug,' ');

console.log(string);
```

Without the {Han} everything works well, but no Chinese chars. Any idea? I want to keep it simple, but this seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest removing all chars other than letters and digits:

```js
let string = 'Test=查看         ';
string = string.replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/ug,' ').trim();
console.log(string);
```

If you need to allow diacritics add `\p{M}` there:

```js
string.replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}]+/ug,' ').trim();
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}]+/: Invalid escape

Comment: Something seems to be wrong :O

Comment: @Mr.Jo Nothing is wrong, you must be using Safari or another non-supporting browser.

Comment: Just to be clear: Why does it only works within browsers and not native JS scripts?

Comment: In my case, I want to use it in a native JS script and not within a browser. That's why I'm asking. I hope u don't mind.

Comment: @Mr.Jo The `u` flag only allows the use of Unicode property classes in ECMAScript 2018+ compliant JS environments,

Comment: Understand. What does this mean for native JS scripts without browser usage executed with NodeJS?

Comment: @Mr.Jo Nodejs regex supports ECMAScript 2018.

Comment: The product I'm working in is using node version 8.9.4. I'm not sure if this is the source of my problems but seems so.

Comment: @Mr.Jo It is, you need to update it.

Comment: It's a huge project. I'm sadly not allowed to update node. Is there any other solution for older versions?

Comment: Yes, transpile the code.

Comment: Is there no other way, like using the real regex instead of the shortcodes? If not, I'll try to find another solution

Comment: I've checked out this answer from you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698470/unicode-ranges-of-pl-plu-and-pll Can this work for this example here? If yes, how would the RegEx look like?

Comment: @Mr.Jo  See [this page](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%5E%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BN%7D%5D&abb=on&esc=on&g=&i=).

Comment: Oh nice tool! Since I want to keep things simple, I opened another question containing more specific stuff instead of always changing this one since it's already been answered quite well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73304472/how-can-i-transform-regex-categories-into-plain-regex