# How can I transform RegEx categories into plain RegEx?

Tags: node.js, regex

This question is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73296489/how-can-i-allow-only-alphanumeric-including-chinese-japanese-and-all-that-crypt/73297446?noredirect=1#comment129448042_73297446) question. During coding, I got some new things popping up and because the initial question is properly answered, I want to describe my issues in this question.

My goal is to have a RegEx which filters out everything, instead of some special requirements:

- Alphanumeric allowed
- non-Lating e.g. Chinese or Japanese allowed
- .,-?!"'=$|<>[]{} allowed
- Works with NodeJS 8.9.4

During implementation of the answer from the main question, I've found out, that this only works with newer Node versions (because of the supported ES version). Sadly, our project runs on `8.9.4` which can't be changed in any way. So upgrading is not an option.

I've started searching around and found this page: https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/tools/output/categories.js

With the help of another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698470/unicode-ranges-of-pl-plu-and-pll), I've tried to build something together which matches my requirements. I came out with:

```
/[^\(?:[A-Za-z\xAA\xB5\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0560-\u0588\u05D0-\u05EA\u05EF-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u066E\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5\u06E6\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u07F4\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u0860-\u086A\u0870-\u0887\u0889-\u088E\u08A0-\u08C9\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0980\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0\u09F1\u09FC\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0AF9\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58-\u0C5A\u0C5D\u0C60\u0C61\u0C80\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDD\u0CDE\u0CE0\u0CE1\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D04-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D54-\u0D56\u0D5F-\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E86-\u0E8A\u0E8C-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7-\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F5\u13F8-\u13FD\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16F1-\u16F8\u1700-\u1711\u171F-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u1820-\u1878\u1880-\u1884\u1887-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4C\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE\u1BAF\u1BBA-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C7D\u1C80-\u1C88]+/g
```

My current example string is:

> Test=查看
> °°^ Marting 10202029 Offline!"§$%&/()!"§$%&/()After this we want to keep the allowed special chars: .,-?!"'=$|<>[]{}

Somehow, the answer from the first question works better as the parsed categories from me. So there must be something wrong, which I'm unable to find.

At the end, I want to put everything inside a `var.replace()` command, to replace everything bad with a single whitespace.

For testing, I'm using: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Ok, so you want to transpile `/[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/gu` into an ES5 compliant regex?

Comment: Yes, by allowing `.,-?!"'=$|<>[]{}` now. This is a new requirement..

Comment: Ok, so `/[^\p{L}\p{N}.,?!"'=$|<>[\]{}-]+/gu`

Comment: Yes, correct. But with parsed categories since NodeJS V8

Comment: Wait, maybe downgrading to ES6 regex is also fine? I mean, your environment supports the `u` flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use [`regexpu`](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/regexpu) to transpile the regex into an ES6-compliant regex, or you may go to the [Unicode Utilities: UnicodeSet](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp) page and get the code point ranges manually.

In your case, paste `[^\p{L}\p{N}]` into the **Input** field, check *Abbreviate* and *Escape*, then click <kbd>Show Set</kbd>. Add the `.,?!"'=$|<>[\]{}-` at the *end* of the character class. Then, double the backslashes (also, escape the `'` or `"`, your string literal delimiter char, I escaped `'` below) and put inside the `pattern_from_uu` variable definition in this JavaScript code and then, all you need to define the regex is `const reg = new RegExp(pattern, "gu")` or `const reg = new RegExp(pattern, "u")`:

```js
const pattern_from_uu = '[^0-9A-Za-z\\u00AA\\u00B2\\u00B3\\u00B5\\u00B9\\u00BA\\u00BC-\\u00BE\\u00C0-\\u00D6\\u00D8-\\u00F6\\u00F8-\\u02C1\\u02C6-\\u02D1\\u02E0-\\u02E4\\u02EC\\u02EE\\u0370-\\u0374\\u0376\\u0377\\u037A-\\u037D\\u037F\\u0386\\u0388-\\u038A\\u038C\\u038E-\\u03A1\\u03A3-\\u03F5\\u03F7-\\u0481\\u048A-\\u052F\\u0531-\\u0556\\u0559\\u0560-\\u0588\\u05D0-\\u05EA\\u05EF-\\u05F2\\u0620-\\u064A\\u0660-\\u0669\\u066E\\u066F\\u0671-\\u06D3\\u06D5\\u06E5\\u06E6\\u06EE-\\u06FC\\u06FF\\u0710\\u0712-\\u072F\\u074D-\\u07A5\\u07B1\\u07C0-\\u07EA\\u07F4\\u07F5\\u07FA\\u0800-\\u0815\\u081A\\u0824\\u0828\\u0840-\\u0858\\u0860-\\u086A\\u0870-\\u0887\\u0889-\\u088E\\u08A0-\\u08C9\\u0904-\\u0939\\u093D\\u0950\\u0958-\\u0961\\u0966-\\u096F\\u0971-\\u0980\\u0985-\\u098C\\u098F\\u0990\\u0993-\\u09A8\\u09AA-\\u09B0\\u09B2\\u09B6-\\u09B9\\u09BD\\u09CE\\u09DC\\u09DD\\u09DF-\\u09E1\\u09E6-\\u09F1\\u09F4-\\u09F9\\u09FC\\u0A05-\\u0A0A\\u0A0F\\u0A10\\u0A13-\\u0A28\\u0A2A-\\u0A30\\u0A32\\u0A33\\u0A35\\u0A36\\u0A38\\u0A39\\u0A59-\\u0A5C\\u0A5E\\u0A66-\\u0A6F\\u0A72-\\u0A74\\u0A85-\\u0A8D\\u0A8F-\\u0A91\\u0A93-\\u0AA8\\u0AAA-\\u0AB0\\u0AB2\\u0AB3\\u0AB5-\\u0AB9\\u0ABD\\u0AD0\\u0AE0\\u0AE1\\u0AE6-\\u0AEF\\u0AF9\\u0B05-\\u0B0C\\u0B0F\\u0B10\\u0B13-\\u0B28\\u0B2A-\\u0B30\\u0B32\\u0B33\\u0B35-\\u0B39\\u0B3D\\u0B5C\\u0B5D\\u0B5F-\\u0B61\\u0B66-\\u0B6F\\u0B71-\\u0B77\\u0B83\\u0B85-\\u0B8A\\u0B8E-\\u0B90\\u0B92-\\u0B95\\u0B99\\u0B9A\\u0B9C\\u0B9E\\u0B9F\\u0BA3\\u0BA4\\u0BA8-\\u0BAA\\u0BAE-\\u0BB9\\u0BD0\\u0BE6-\\u0BF2\\u0C05-\\u0C0C\\u0C0E-\\u0C10\\u0C12-\\u0C28\\u0C2A-\\u0C39\\u0C3D\\u0C58-\\u0C5A\\u0C5D\\u0C60\\u0C61\\u0C66-\\u0C6F\\u0C78-\\u0C7E\\u0C80\\u0C85-\\u0C8C\\u0C8E-\\u0C90\\u0C92-\\u0CA8\\u0CAA-\\u0CB3\\u0CB5-\\u0CB9\\u0CBD\\u0CDD\\u0CDE\\u0CE0\\u0CE1\\u0CE6-\\u0CEF\\u0CF1\\u0CF2\\u0D04-\\u0D0C\\u0D0E-\\u0D10\\u0D12-\\u0D3A\\u0D3D\\u0D4E\\u0D54-\\u0D56\\u0D58-\\u0D61\\u0D66-\\u0D78\\u0D7A-\\u0D7F\\u0D85-\\u0D96\\u0D9A-\\u0DB1\\u0DB3-\\u0DBB\\u0DBD\\u0DC0-\\u0DC6\\u0DE6-\\u0DEF\\u0E01-\\u0E30\\u0E32\\u0E33\\u0E40-\\u0E46\\u0E50-\\u0E59\\u0E81\\u0E82\\u0E84\\u0E86-\\u0E8A\\u0E8C-\\u0EA3\\u0EA5\\u0EA7-\\u0EB0\\u0EB2\\u0EB3\\u0EBD\\u0EC0-\\u0EC4\\u0EC6\\u0ED0-\\u0ED9\\u0EDC-\\u0EDF\\u0F00\\u0F20-\\u0F33\\u0F40-\\u0F47\\u0F49-\\u0F6C\\u0F88-\\u0F8C\\u1000-\\u102A\\u103F-\\u1049\\u1050-\\u1055\\u105A-\\u105D\\u1061\\u1065\\u1066\\u106E-\\u1070\\u1075-\\u1081\\u108E\\u1090-\\u1099\\u10A0-\\u10C5\\u10C7\\u10CD\\u10D0-\\u10FA\\u10FC-\\u1248\\u124A-\\u124D\\u1250-\\u1256\\u1258\\u125A-\\u125D\\u1260-\\u1288\\u128A-\\u128D\\u1290-\\u12B0\\u12B2-\\u12B5\\u12B8-\\u12BE\\u12C0\\u12C2-\\u12C5\\u12C8-\\u12D6\\u12D8-\\u1310\\u1312-\\u1315\\u1318-\\u135A\\u1369-\\u137C\\u1380-\\u138F\\u13A0-\\u13F5\\u13F8-\\u13FD\\u1401-\\u166C\\u166F-\\u167F\\u1681-\\u169A\\u16A0-\\u16EA\\u16EE-\\u16F8\\u1700-\\u1711\\u171F-\\u1731\\u1740-\\u1751\\u1760-\\u176C\\u176E-\\u1770\\u1780-\\u17B3\\u17D7\\u17DC\\u17E0-\\u17E9\\u17F0-\\u17F9\\u1810-\\u1819\\u1820-\\u1878\\u1880-\\u1884\\u1887-\\u18A8\\u18AA\\u18B0-\\u18F5\\u1900-\\u191E\\u1946-\\u196D\\u1970-\\u1974\\u1980-\\u19AB\\u19B0-\\u19C9\\u19D0-\\u19DA\\u1A00-\\u1A16\\u1A20-\\u1A54\\u1A80-\\u1A89\\u1A90-\\u1A99\\u1AA7\\u1B05-\\u1B33\\u1B45-\\u1B4C\\u1B50-\\u1B59\\u1B83-\\u1BA0\\u1BAE-\\u1BE5\\u1C00-\\u1C23\\u1C40-\\u1C49\\u1C4D-\\u1C7D\\u1C80-\\u1C88\\u1C90-\\u1CBA\\u1CBD-\\u1CBF\\u1CE9-\\u1CEC\\u1CEE-\\u1CF3\\u1CF5\\u1CF6\\u1CFA\\u1D00-\\u1DBF\\u1E00-\\u1F15\\u1F18-\\u1F1D\\u1F20-\\u1F45\\u1F48-\\u1F4D\\u1F50-\\u1F57\\u1F59\\u1F5B\\u1F5D\\u1F5F-\\u1F7D\\u1F80-\\u1FB4\\u1FB6-\\u1FBC\\u1FBE\\u1FC2-\\u1FC4\\u1FC6-\\u1FCC\\u1FD0-\\u1FD3\\u1FD6-\\u1FDB\\u1FE0-\\u1FEC\\u1FF2-\\u1FF4\\u1FF6-\\u1FFC\\u2070\\u2071\\u2074-\\u2079\\u207F-\\u2089\\u2090-\\u209C\\u2102\\u2107\\u210A-\\u2113\\u2115\\u2119-\\u211D\\u2124\\u2126\\u2128\\u212A-\\u212D\\u212F-\\u2139\\u213C-\\u213F\\u2145-\\u2149\\u214E\\u2150-\\u2189\\u2460-\\u249B\\u24EA-\\u24FF\\u2776-\\u2793\\u2C00-\\u2CE4\\u2CEB-\\u2CEE\\u2CF2\\u2CF3\\u2CFD\\u2D00-\\u2D25\\u2D27\\u2D2D\\u2D30-\\u2D67\\u2D6F\\u2D80-\\u2D96\\u2DA0-\\u2DA6\\u2DA8-\\u2DAE\\u2DB0-\\u2DB6\\u2DB8-\\u2DBE\\u2DC0-\\u2DC6\\u2DC8-\\u2DCE\\u2DD0-\\u2DD6\\u2DD8-\\u2DDE\\u2E2F\\u3005-\\u3007\\u3021-\\u3029\\u3031-\\u3035\\u3038-\\u303C\\u3041-\\u3096\\u309D-\\u309F\\u30A1-\\u30FA\\u30FC-\\u30FF\\u3105-\\u312F\\u3131-\\u318E\\u3192-\\u3195\\u31A0-\\u31BF\\u31F0-\\u31FF\\u3220-\\u3229\\u3248-\\u324F\\u3251-\\u325F\\u3280-\\u3289\\u32B1-\\u32BF\\u3400-\\u4DBF\\u4E00-\\uA48C\\uA4D0-\\uA4FD\\uA500-\\uA60C\\uA610-\\uA62B\\uA640-\\uA66E\\uA67F-\\uA69D\\uA6A0-\\uA6EF\\uA717-\\uA71F\\uA722-\\uA788\\uA78B-\\uA7CA\\uA7D0\\uA7D1\\uA7D3\\uA7D5-\\uA7D9\\uA7F2-\\uA801\\uA803-\\uA805\\uA807-\\uA80A\\uA80C-\\uA822\\uA830-\\uA835\\uA840-\\uA873\\uA882-\\uA8B3\\uA8D0-\\uA8D9\\uA8F2-\\uA8F7\\uA8FB\\uA8FD\\uA8FE\\uA900-\\uA925\\uA930-\\uA946\\uA960-\\uA97C\\uA984-\\uA9B2\\uA9CF-\\uA9D9\\uA9E0-\\uA9E4\\uA9E6-\\uA9FE\\uAA00-\\uAA28\\uAA40-\\uAA42\\uAA44-\\uAA4B\\uAA50-\\uAA59\\uAA60-\\uAA76\\uAA7A\\uAA7E-\\uAAAF\\uAAB1\\uAAB5\\uAAB6\\uAAB9-\\uAABD\\uAAC0\\uAAC2\\uAADB-\\uAADD\\uAAE0-\\uAAEA\\uAAF2-\\uAAF4\\uAB01-\\uAB06\\uAB09-\\uAB0E\\uAB11-\\uAB16\\uAB20-\\uAB26\\uAB28-\\uAB2E\\uAB30-\\uAB5A\\uAB5C-\\uAB69\\uAB70-\\uABE2\\uABF0-\\uABF9\\uAC00-\\uD7A3\\uD7B0-\\uD7C6\\uD7CB-\\uD7FB\\uF900-\\uFA6D\\uFA70-\\uFAD9\\uFB00-\\uFB06\\uFB13-\\uFB17\\uFB1D\\uFB1F-\\uFB28\\uFB2A-\\uFB36\\uFB38-\\uFB3C\\uFB3E\\uFB40\\uFB41\\uFB43\\uFB44\\uFB46-\\uFBB1\\uFBD3-\\uFD3D\\uFD50-\\uFD8F\\uFD92-\\uFDC7\\uFDF0-\\uFDFB\\uFE70-\\uFE74\\uFE76-\\uFEFC\\uFF10-\\uFF19\\uFF21-\\uFF3A\\uFF41-\\uFF5A\\uFF66-\\uFFBE\\uFFC2-\\uFFC7\\uFFCA-\\uFFCF\\uFFD2-\\uFFD7\\uFFDA-\\uFFDC\\U00010000-\\U0001000B\\U0001000D-\\U00010026\\U00010028-\\U0001003A\\U0001003C\\U0001003D\\U0001003F-\\U0001004D\\U00010050-\\U0001005D\\U00010080-\\U000100FA\\U00010107-\\U00010133\\U00010140-\\U00010178\\U0001018A\\U0001018B\\U00010280-\\U0001029C\\U000102A0-\\U000102D0\\U000102E1-\\U000102FB\\U00010300-\\U00010323\\U0001032D-\\U0001034A\\U00010350-\\U00010375\\U00010380-\\U0001039D\\U000103A0-\\U000103C3\\U000103C8-\\U000103CF\\U000103D1-\\U000103D5\\U00010400-\\U0001049D\\U000104A0-\\U000104A9\\U000104B0-\\U000104D3\\U000104D8-\\U000104FB\\U00010500-\\U00010527\\U00010530-\\U00010563\\U00010570-\\U0001057A\\U0001057C-\\U0001058A\\U0001058C-\\U00010592\\U00010594\\U00010595\\U00010597-\\U000105A1\\U000105A3-\\U000105B1\\U000105B3-\\U000105B9\\U000105BB\\U000105BC\\U00010600-\\U00010736\\U00010740-\\U00010755\\U00010760-\\U00010767\\U00010780-\\U00010785\\U00010787-\\U000107B0\\U000107B2-\\U000107BA\\U00010800-\\U00010805\\U00010808\\U0001080A-\\U00010835\\U00010837\\U00010838\\U0001083C\\U0001083F-\\U00010855\\U00010858-\\U00010876\\U00010879-\\U0001089E\\U000108A7-\\U000108AF\\U000108E0-\\U000108F2\\U000108F4\\U000108F5\\U000108FB-\\U0001091B\\U00010920-\\U00010939\\U00010980-\\U000109B7\\U000109BC-\\U000109CF\\U000109D2-\\U00010A00\\U00010A10-\\U00010A13\\U00010A15-\\U00010A17\\U00010A19-\\U00010A35\\U00010A40-\\U00010A48\\U00010A60-\\U00010A7E\\U00010A80-\\U00010A9F\\U00010AC0-\\U00010AC7\\U00010AC9-\\U00010AE4\\U00010AEB-\\U00010AEF\\U00010B00-\\U00010B35\\U00010B40-\\U00010B55\\U00010B58-\\U00010B72\\U00010B78-\\U00010B91\\U00010BA9-\\U00010BAF\\U00010C00-\\U00010C48\\U00010C80-\\U00010CB2\\U00010CC0-\\U00010CF2\\U00010CFA-\\U00010D23\\U00010D30-\\U00010D39\\U00010E60-\\U00010E7E\\U00010E80-\\U00010EA9\\U00010EB0\\U00010EB1\\U00010F00-\\U00010F27\\U00010F30-\\U00010F45\\U00010F51-\\U00010F54\\U00010F70-\\U00010F81\\U00010FB0-\\U00010FCB\\U00010FE0-\\U00010FF6\\U00011003-\\U00011037\\U00011052-\\U0001106F\\U00011071\\U00011072\\U00011075\\U00011083-\\U000110AF\\U000110D0-\\U000110E8\\U000110F0-\\U000110F9\\U00011103-\\U00011126\\U00011136-\\U0001113F\\U00011144\\U00011147\\U00011150-\\U00011172\\U00011176\\U00011183-\\U000111B2\\U000111C1-\\U000111C4\\U000111D0-\\U000111DA\\U000111DC\\U000111E1-\\U000111F4\\U00011200-\\U00011211\\U00011213-\\U0001122B\\U00011280-\\U00011286\\U00011288\\U0001128A-\\U0001128D\\U0001128F-\\U0001129D\\U0001129F-\\U000112A8\\U000112B0-\\U000112DE\\U000112F0-\\U000112F9\\U00011305-\\U0001130C\\U0001130F\\U00011310\\U00011313-\\U00011328\\U0001132A-\\U00011330\\U00011332\\U00011333\\U00011335-\\U00011339\\U0001133D\\U00011350\\U0001135D-\\U00011361\\U00011400-\\U00011434\\U00011447-\\U0001144A\\U00011450-\\U00011459\\U0001145F-\\U00011461\\U00011480-\\U000114AF\\U000114C4\\U000114C5\\U000114C7\\U000114D0-\\U000114D9\\U00011580-\\U000115AE\\U000115D8-\\U000115DB\\U00011600-\\U0001162F\\U00011644\\U00011650-\\U00011659\\U00011680-\\U000116AA\\U000116B8\\U000116C0-\\U000116C9\\U00011700-\\U0001171A\\U00011730-\\U0001173B\\U00011740-\\U00011746\\U00011800-\\U0001182B\\U000118A0-\\U000118F2\\U000118FF-\\U00011906\\U00011909\\U0001190C-\\U00011913\\U00011915\\U00011916\\U00011918-\\U0001192F\\U0001193F\\U00011941\\U00011950-\\U00011959\\U000119A0-\\U000119A7\\U000119AA-\\U000119D0\\U000119E1\\U000119E3\\U00011A00\\U00011A0B-\\U00011A32\\U00011A3A\\U00011A50\\U00011A5C-\\U00011A89\\U00011A9D\\U00011AB0-\\U00011AF8\\U00011C00-\\U00011C08\\U00011C0A-\\U00011C2E\\U00011C40\\U00011C50-\\U00011C6C\\U00011C72-\\U00011C8F\\U00011D00-\\U00011D06\\U00011D08\\U00011D09\\U00011D0B-\\U00011D30\\U00011D46\\U00011D50-\\U00011D59\\U00011D60-\\U00011D65\\U00011D67\\U00011D68\\U00011D6A-\\U00011D89\\U00011D98\\U00011DA0-\\U00011DA9\\U00011EE0-\\U00011EF2\\U00011FB0\\U00011FC0-\\U00011FD4\\U00012000-\\U00012399\\U00012400-\\U0001246E\\U00012480-\\U00012543\\U00012F90-\\U00012FF0\\U00013000-\\U0001342E\\U00014400-\\U00014646\\U00016800-\\U00016A38\\U00016A40-\\U00016A5E\\U00016A60-\\U00016A69\\U00016A70-\\U00016ABE\\U00016AC0-\\U00016AC9\\U00016AD0-\\U00016AED\\U00016B00-\\U00016B2F\\U00016B40-\\U00016B43\\U00016B50-\\U00016B59\\U00016B5B-\\U00016B61\\U00016B63-\\U00016B77\\U00016B7D-\\U00016B8F\\U00016E40-\\U00016E96\\U00016F00-\\U00016F4A\\U00016F50\\U00016F93-\\U00016F9F\\U00016FE0\\U00016FE1\\U00016FE3\\U00017000-\\U000187F7\\U00018800-\\U00018CD5\\U00018D00-\\U00018D08\\U0001AFF0-\\U0001AFF3\\U0001AFF5-\\U0001AFFB\\U0001AFFD\\U0001AFFE\\U0001B000-\\U0001B122\\U0001B150-\\U0001B152\\U0001B164-\\U0001B167\\U0001B170-\\U0001B2FB\\U0001BC00-\\U0001BC6A\\U0001BC70-\\U0001BC7C\\U0001BC80-\\U0001BC88\\U0001BC90-\\U0001BC99\\U0001D2E0-\\U0001D2F3\\U0001D360-\\U0001D378\\U0001D400-\\U0001D454\\U0001D456-\\U0001D49C\\U0001D49E\\U0001D49F\\U0001D4A2\\U0001D4A5\\U0001D4A6\\U0001D4A9-\\U0001D4AC\\U0001D4AE-\\U0001D4B9\\U0001D4BB\\U0001D4BD-\\U0001D4C3\\U0001D4C5-\\U0001D505\\U0001D507-\\U0001D50A\\U0001D50D-\\U0001D514\\U0001D516-\\U0001D51C\\U0001D51E-\\U0001D539\\U0001D53B-\\U0001D53E\\U0001D540-\\U0001D544\\U0001D546\\U0001D54A-\\U0001D550\\U0001D552-\\U0001D6A5\\U0001D6A8-\\U0001D6C0\\U0001D6C2-\\U0001D6DA\\U0001D6DC-\\U0001D6FA\\U0001D6FC-\\U0001D714\\U0001D716-\\U0001D734\\U0001D736-\\U0001D74E\\U0001D750-\\U0001D76E\\U0001D770-\\U0001D788\\U0001D78A-\\U0001D7A8\\U0001D7AA-\\U0001D7C2\\U0001D7C4-\\U0001D7CB\\U0001D7CE-\\U0001D7FF\\U0001DF00-\\U0001DF1E\\U0001E100-\\U0001E12C\\U0001E137-\\U0001E13D\\U0001E140-\\U0001E149\\U0001E14E\\U0001E290-\\U0001E2AD\\U0001E2C0-\\U0001E2EB\\U0001E2F0-\\U0001E2F9\\U0001E7E0-\\U0001E7E6\\U0001E7E8-\\U0001E7EB\\U0001E7ED\\U0001E7EE\\U0001E7F0-\\U0001E7FE\\U0001E800-\\U0001E8C4\\U0001E8C7-\\U0001E8CF\\U0001E900-\\U0001E943\\U0001E94B\\U0001E950-\\U0001E959\\U0001EC71-\\U0001ECAB\\U0001ECAD-\\U0001ECAF\\U0001ECB1-\\U0001ECB4\\U0001ED01-\\U0001ED2D\\U0001ED2F-\\U0001ED3D\\U0001EE00-\\U0001EE03\\U0001EE05-\\U0001EE1F\\U0001EE21\\U0001EE22\\U0001EE24\\U0001EE27\\U0001EE29-\\U0001EE32\\U0001EE34-\\U0001EE37\\U0001EE39\\U0001EE3B\\U0001EE42\\U0001EE47\\U0001EE49\\U0001EE4B\\U0001EE4D-\\U0001EE4F\\U0001EE51\\U0001EE52\\U0001EE54\\U0001EE57\\U0001EE59\\U0001EE5B\\U0001EE5D\\U0001EE5F\\U0001EE61\\U0001EE62\\U0001EE64\\U0001EE67-\\U0001EE6A\\U0001EE6C-\\U0001EE72\\U0001EE74-\\U0001EE77\\U0001EE79-\\U0001EE7C\\U0001EE7E\\U0001EE80-\\U0001EE89\\U0001EE8B-\\U0001EE9B\\U0001EEA1-\\U0001EEA3\\U0001EEA5-\\U0001EEA9\\U0001EEAB-\\U0001EEBB\\U0001F100-\\U0001F10C\\U0001FBF0-\\U0001FBF9\\U00020000-\\U0002A6DF\\U0002A700-\\U0002B738\\U0002B740-\\U0002B81D\\U0002B820-\\U0002CEA1\\U0002CEB0-\\U0002EBE0\\U0002F800-\\U0002FA1D\\U00030000-\\U0003134A.,?!"\'=$|<>[\\]{}-]';
let pattern = pattern_from_uu.replace(/\\U000([a-f\d]+)/gi, "\\u{$1}");
console.log("Your regex is:\n/" + pattern + "/gu");
const texts = ["Test=查看","°°^ Marting 10202029 Offline!\"§$%&/()!\"§$%&/()After this we want to keep the allowed special chars: .,-?!\"'=$|<>[]{}"];
const reg = new RegExp(pattern, "gu")
for (const text of texts) {
    console.log(text.replace(reg, ""));
}
```

See the [generated regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p2VK43/1).

Comment: If I do exactly what u say, I'm getting a new error from the constructor of new RegExp: `Range out of order in character class`

Comment: @Mr.Jo You must have left out the `u` flag.

Comment: Looks great! I was just wondering why nothing happens when I change the replacement value within the loop?

Comment: @Mr.Jo No idea what you mean. You want to remove the unwanted chars, the replacement must be empty.

Comment: Yes, sure sure, but can I change the replace value? I thought yes, inside the loop instead of `""` I've tried `" "` but it's totally ignoring.

Comment: @Mr.Jo No, replacement with space works, I get `Test= 查看` and ``'    Marting 10202029 Offline!" $     !" $     After this we want to keep the allowed s'``